# Permissions error when using WebPi under Cygwin SSH

Tags: ssh, cygwin, web-platform-installer

Trying to install web package in WebPI via Cygwin SSH (for automation) returns this error:
There was an error reading IIS configuration schema from 'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\'.

When launched from the desktop Cygwin it works fine.

Any idea what permissions might be missing, and how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by substituting a "Windows" environment, for example:

```
set ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
set APPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming
set CLIENTNAME=RUSLANIUM
set CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
set CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
set CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
set COMPUTERNAME=WIN-3H007575N4K
set ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
set FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\Users\Administrator
set LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local
set LOGONSERVER=\\WIN-3H007575N4K
set NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=1
set OS=Windows_NT
```